# how to read list so that it prints the exact number of lines of that not more?

Tags: python-3.x, nlp

EDIT: I have a text file that contains a Persian sentence, a tab and theد an English word in each line. I omitted stop words and punctuation and put the result in a list (witoutStops). Now I have to see if the words in "s" are in each line of the witoutStop list, put "1" instead of that and if not put "0". For example if the list has 10 lines, the output file should have 10 lines of 1 and 0, too with 6 columns (5 are for the words in "s" list and 1 is for the English word). But the problem is, it returns 30 lines. How can I fix it?

```
from hazm import*
from collections import Counter
import collections
import math

punctuation = '!"#$%&\'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~،؟«؛«'

file1 = "stopwords.txt"
file2 = "test files/golTest.txt"


witoutStops = []
corpuslines = []

def RemStopWords(file1, file2):  
    with open(file1, encoding = "utf-8") as stopfile:
        normalizer = Normalizer()
        stopwords = stopfile.read()
        stopwords = normalizer.normalize(stopwords)
        with open(file2, encoding = "utf-8") as trainfile:
            for line in trainfile:
                tmp = line.strip().split("\t")
                tmp[0] = normalizer.normalize(tmp[0])
                for i in punctuation:  # delete punctuations
                    if i in tmp[0]:
                        tmp[0] = tmp[0].replace(i, "")
                corpuslines.append(tmp)
                for row in corpuslines:
                    line = ""
                    tokens = row[0].split()# delete stop words
                    for token in tokens: 
                        if token not in stopwords:
                            line += token + " "
                line = line.strip() + "\t" + row[1] + "\n"
                witoutStops.append (line)
#print (witoutStops)
#print (corpuslines)

s = ['آبی', 'منابع', 'سبز', 'رنگ', 'زرد']

def vector():
RemStopWords(file1, file2)
for line in witoutStops:
    with open ("Train.arff", "a", encoding = "utf-8") as f:   
    line = line.split("\t")
    words = line[0].split()
    for i in s:
        if any([i == word for word in words]): 
            f.write('1,')
        else: 
            f.write('0,')
```

Example of the file (and witoutStop list):

[image]

the output should have 5 columns (the words in "s" list) + a column of the English word. And 10 rows.

Hint: This is a part of a bigger code. so It has some other functions to extract the words for "s" list (which are actually 1000 most frequent words of the file). I put these 5 words here as an example here.

Comment: Are you wanting to `iter`ate over each of the lines in the `toread` file?

Comment: `iter` should work just as well for lists as it does for files, although the way you're using it it's not necessary for either (you could just use `for line in toread:`). What happens when you try to run that with `toread` as a list, rather than a file?

Comment: @glibdud, for example if the list has 10 lines, in the out put it should return 10 lines, too. But the problem is, it returns 30 lines! How can I fix it?

Comment: Please add the code you're using with the list, along with a demonstration of the behavior your seeing. We'll need to know what the contents of the list are, and what the "30 lines" are that are resulting from it.

Answer (score 0):

Given a tab separated file:

```
$ cat test.txt 
زرد رنگ سبز منابع آبی   Yellow-green color of water resources
زرد رنگ سبز منابع آبی   Yellow-green color of water resources
```

Here's an idiomatic way to read the columns of the file:

```
with open('test.txt', 'r') as fin:
    for line in fin:
        persian, english = line.strip().split('\t')
        # Do something
        print (persian)
```

You can also read a tab-separated file as dataframe, e.g. with `pandas`:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> pd.read_csv('test.txt', delimiter='\t', header=None)
                       0                                      1
0  زرد رنگ سبز منابع آبی  Yellow-green color of water resources
1  زرد رنگ سبز منابع آبی  Yellow-green color of water resources
>>> df = pd.read_csv('test.txt', delimiter='\t', header=None)
>>> df.rename(columns={0:'persian', 1:'english'})
                 persian                                english
0  زرد رنگ سبز منابع آبی  Yellow-green color of water resources
1  زرد رنگ سبز منابع آبی  Yellow-green color of water resources
>>> df = df.rename(columns={0:'persian', 1:'english'})
>>> df['persian']
0    زرد رنگ سبز منابع آبی
1    زرد رنگ سبز منابع آبی
Name: persian, dtype: object
>>> print (df['persian'][0])
زرد رنگ سبز منابع آبی
>>> print (df['english'][0])
Yellow-green color of water resources
```

To write the columns out to a new file:

```
with open('test.txt', 'r') as fin, open('p.txt', 'w') as pfout, open('e.txt', 'w') as efout:
    for line in fin:
        persian, english = line.strip().split('\t')
        pfout.write(persian+'\n')
        efout.write(english+'\n')
```

And if you want to remove stopwords before writing to file:

```
stopwords = ['of', 'in', 'the']
with open('test.txt', 'r') as fin, open('p.txt', 'w') as pfout, open('e.txt', 'w') as efout:
    for line in fin:
        persian, english = line.strip().split('\t')
        english_no_stop = [w for w in english.split() if w not in stopwords]
        # Concatenate the list into a string
        english_no_stop = ' '.join(english_no_stop)
        pfout.write(persian+'\n')
        efout.write(english_no_stop +'\n')
```